# Plugin Bootstrap Typeahead + PHP e MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap-3, typeahead

Estou a alguns dias tentando utilizar o recurso de autocompletar Typeahead do Bootstrap com este plugin:[biggora/bootstrap-ajax-typeahead](https://github.com/biggora/bootstrap-ajax-typeahead).
Após pesquisar bastante, achei apenas respostas vagas, mas nada de conclusivo sobre como usar este plugin buscando dados do MySQL.
Alguém já utilizou este plugin ou o próprio Typeahead para Bootstrap 3 buscando dados do MySQL e que possa me ajudar?
Qualquer ajuda será bem-vinda.
Valeu!

Comment: Seja bem-vindo ao SOpt! Seria legal você postar os códigos de sua tentativa e o erro que você está tendo :)

Comment: Obrigado pelas boas vindas. Na realidade segui as instruções do do desenvolvedor do plug-in que citei na pergunta. Revisando o código, o problema era que, sem querer, eu estava incluindo o jquery 2 vezes, sendo que na segunda vez era uma versão desatualizada. Removi essa segunda inclusão e tudo funcionou.
Valeu!